# Eigen library with C++11 multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, parallel-processing, eigen

I have a code to compute a Gaussian Mixture Model with Expectation Maximization in order to identify the clusters from a given input data sample.

A piece of the code is repeating the computation of such model for a number of trials **Ntrials** (one indepenendet of the other but using the same input data) in order to finally pick up the best solution (the one maximizing the total likelihood from the model). This concept can be generalized to many other clustering algorithms (e.g. k-means).

I want to parallelize the part of the code that has to be repeated **Ntrials** times through multi-threading with C++11 such that each thread will execute one trial.

A code example, assuming an input `Eigen::ArrayXXd sample` of (Ndimensions x Npoints) can be of the type:

```
    double bestTotalModelProbability = 0;
    Eigen::ArrayXd clusterIndicesFromSample(Npoints);
    clusterIndicesFromSample.setZero();

    for (int i=0; i < Ntrials; i++)
    {
         totalModelProbability = computeGaussianMixtureModel(sample);


         // Check if this trial is better than the previous one.
         // If so, update the results (cluster index for each point
         // in the sample) and keep them.

         if totalModelProbability > bestTotalModelProbability
         {
             bestTotalModelProbability = totalModelProbability;
             ...
             clusterIndicesFromSample = obtainClusterMembership(sample);
         }
    }
```

where I pass the reference value of sample (Eigen::Ref), and not sample itself to both the functions **computeGaussianMixtureModel()** and **obtainClusterMembership()**.

My code is heavily based on Eigen array, and the N-dimensional problems that I take can account for order 10-100 dimensions and 500-1000 different sample points. I am looking for some examples to create a multi-threaded version of this code using Eigen arrays and std:thread of C++11, but could not find anything around and I am struggling with making even some simple examples for manipulation of Eigen arrays.

I am not even sure Eigen can be used within std::thread in C++11.
Can someone help me even with some simple example to understand the synthax?
I am using clang++ as compiler in Mac OSX on a CPU with 6 cores (12 threads).

Comment: Why couldn't eigen be used inside a thread? Using C++11 threads directly is painful, I strongly recommend you use some language extension (openmp, openacc, etc) or a library (TBB, etc) to make it easier.

Comment: Looks like the trial number `i` depends on the previous one, so it might be easier to parallelize the functions `computeGaussianMixtureModel` and `obtainClusterMembership` themself, and as said Marc Glisse, I'd also recommend to begin with OpenMP which is much easier to use.

Answer (score 2):

OP's question attracted my attention because number-crunching with speed-up earned by multi-threading is one of the top todo's on my personal list.

I must admit that my experience with the Eigen library is very limited. (I once used the decompose of 3×3 rotation matrices to Euler angles which is very clever solved in a general way in the Eigen library.)

Hence, I defined another sample task consisting of a stupid counting of values in a sample data set.

This is done multiple times (using the same evaluation function):

1. single threaded (to get a value for comparison)
2. starting each sub-task in an extra thread (in an admittedly rather stupid approach)
3. starting threads with interleaved access to sample data
4. starting threads with partitioned access to sample data.

`test-multi-threading.cc`:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

// a sample function to process a certain amount of data
template <typename T>
size_t countFrequency(
  size_t n, const T data[], const T &begin, const T &end)
{
  size_t result = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) result += data[i] >= begin && data[i] < end;
  return result;
}

typedef std::uint16_t Value;
typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;
typedef std::chrono::microseconds MuSecs;
typedef decltype(std::chrono::duration_cast<MuSecs>(Clock::now() - Clock::now())) Time;

Time duration(const Clock::time_point &t0)
{
  return std::chrono::duration_cast<MuSecs>(Clock::now() - t0);
}

std::vector<Time> makeTest()
{
  const Value SizeGroup = 4, NGroups = 10000, N = SizeGroup * NGroups;
  const size_t NThreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
  // make a test sample
  std::vector<Value> sample(N);
  for (Value &value : sample) value = (Value)rand();
  // prepare result vectors
  std::vector<size_t> results4[4] = {
    std::vector<size_t>(NGroups, 0),
    std::vector<size_t>(NGroups, 0),
    std::vector<size_t>(NGroups, 0),
    std::vector<size_t>(NGroups, 0)
  };
  // make test
  std::vector<Time> times{
    [&]() { // single threading
      // make a copy of test sample
      std::vector<Value> data(sample);
      std::vector<size_t> &results = results4[0];
      // remember start time
      const Clock::time_point t0 = Clock::now();
      // do experiment single-threaded
      for (size_t i = 0; i < NGroups; ++i) {
        results[i] = countFrequency(data.size(), data.data(),
          (Value)(i * SizeGroup), (Value)((i + 1) * SizeGroup));
      }
      // done
      return duration(t0);
    }(),
    [&]() { // multi-threading - stupid aproach
      // make a copy of test sample
      std::vector<Value> data(sample);
      std::vector<size_t> &results = results4[1];
      // remember start time
      const Clock::time_point t0 = Clock::now();
      // do experiment multi-threaded
      std::vector<std::thread> threads(NThreads);
      for (Value i = 0; i < NGroups;) {
        size_t nT = 0;
        for (; nT < NThreads && i < NGroups; ++nT, ++i) {
          threads[nT] = std::move(std::thread(
            [i, &results, &data, SizeGroup]() {
              size_t result = countFrequency(data.size(), data.data(),
                (Value)(i * SizeGroup), (Value)((i + 1) * SizeGroup));
              results[i] = result;
            }));
        }
        for (size_t iT = 0; iT < nT; ++iT) threads[iT].join();
      }
      // done
      return duration(t0);
    }(),
    [&]() { // multi-threading - interleaved
      // make a copy of test sample
      std::vector<Value> data(sample);
      std::vector<size_t> &results = results4[2];
      // remember start time
      const Clock::time_point t0 = Clock::now();
      // do experiment multi-threaded
      std::vector<std::thread> threads(NThreads);
      for (Value iT = 0; iT < NThreads; ++iT) {
        threads[iT] = std::move(std::thread(
          [iT, &results, &data, NGroups, SizeGroup, NThreads]() {
            for (Value i = iT; i < NGroups; i += NThreads) {
              size_t result = countFrequency(data.size(), data.data(),
                (Value)(i * SizeGroup), (Value)((i + 1) * SizeGroup));
              results[i] = result;
            }
          }));
      }
      for (std::thread &threadI : threads) threadI.join();
      // done
      return duration(t0);
    }(),
    [&]() { // multi-threading - grouped
      std::vector<Value> data(sample);
      std::vector<size_t> &results = results4[3];
      // remember start time
      const Clock::time_point t0 = Clock::now();
      // do experiment multi-threaded
      std::vector<std::thread> threads(NThreads);
      for (Value iT = 0; iT < NThreads; ++iT) {
        threads[iT] = std::move(std::thread(
          [iT, &results, &data, NGroups, SizeGroup, NThreads]() {
            for (Value i = iT * NGroups / NThreads,
              iN = (iT + 1) * NGroups / NThreads; i < iN; ++i) {
              size_t result = countFrequency(data.size(), data.data(),
                (Value)(i * SizeGroup), (Value)((i + 1) * SizeGroup));
              results[i] = result;
            }
          }));
      }
      for (std::thread &threadI : threads) threadI.join();
      // done
      return duration(t0);
    }()
  };
  // check results (must be equal for any kind of computation)
  const unsigned nResults = sizeof results4 / sizeof *results4;
  for (unsigned i = 1; i < nResults; ++i) {
    size_t nErrors = 0;
    for (Value j = 0; j < NGroups; ++j) {
      if (results4[0][j] != results4[i][j]) {
        ++nErrors;
#ifdef _DEBUG
        std::cerr
          << "results4[0][" << j << "]: " << results4[0][j]
          << " != results4[" << i << "][" << j << "]: " << results4[i][j]
          << "!\n";
#endif // _DEBUG
      }
    }
    if (nErrors) std::cerr << nErrors << " errors in results4[" << i << "]!\n";
  }
  // done
  return times;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "std::thread::hardware_concurrency(): "
    << std::thread::hardware_concurrency() << '\n';
  // heat up
  std::cout << "Heat up...\n";
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < 3; ++i) makeTest();
  // repeat NTrials times
  const unsigned NTrials = 10;
  std::cout << "Measuring " << NTrials << " runs...\n"
    << "   "
    << " | " << std::setw(10) << "Single"
    << " | " << std::setw(10) << "Multi 1"
    << " | " << std::setw(10) << "Multi 2"
    << " | " << std::setw(10) << "Multi 3"
    << '\n';
  std::vector<double> sumTimes;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < NTrials; ++i) {
    std::vector<Time> times = makeTest();
    std::cout << std::setw(2) << (i + 1) << ".";
    for (const Time &time : times) {
      std::cout << " | " << std::setw(10) << time.count();
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    sumTimes.resize(times.size(), 0.0);
    for (size_t j = 0; j < times.size(); ++j) sumTimes[j] += times[j].count();
  }
  std::cout << "Average Values:\n   ";
  for (const double &sumTime : sumTimes) {
    std::cout << " | "
      << std::setw(10) << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1)
      << sumTime / NTrials;
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
  std::cout << "Ratio:\n   ";
  for (const double &sumTime : sumTimes) {
    std::cout << " | "
      << std::setw(10) << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3)
      << sumTime / sumTimes.front();
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled and tested on [cygwin64](http://www.cygwin.org) on Windows 10:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 7.3.0

$ g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -o test-multi-threading test-multi-threading.cc

$ ./test-multi-threading
std::thread::hardware_concurrency(): 8
Heat up...
Measuring 10 runs...
    |     Single |    Multi 1 |    Multi 2 |    Multi 3
 1. |     384008 |    1052937 |     130662 |     138411
 2. |     386500 |    1103281 |     133030 |     132576
 3. |     382968 |    1078988 |     137123 |     137780
 4. |     395158 |    1120752 |     138731 |     138650
 5. |     385870 |    1105885 |     144825 |     129405
 6. |     366724 |    1071788 |     137684 |     130289
 7. |     352204 |    1104191 |     133675 |     130505
 8. |     331679 |    1072299 |     135476 |     138257
 9. |     373416 |    1053881 |     138467 |     137613
10. |     370872 |    1096424 |     136810 |     147960
Average Values:
    |   372939.9 |  1086042.6 |   136648.3 |   136144.6
Ratio:
    |      1.000 |      2.912 |      0.366 |      0.365
```

I did the same on coliru.com. (I had to reduce the heat up cycles and the sample size as I exceeded the time limit with the original values.):

```
g++ (GCC) 8.1.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

std::thread::hardware_concurrency(): 4
Heat up...
Measuring 10 runs...
    |     Single |    Multi 1 |    Multi 2 |    Multi 3
 1. |     224684 |     297729 |      48334 |      39016
 2. |     146232 |     337222 |      66308 |      59994
 3. |     195750 |     344056 |      61383 |      63172
 4. |     198629 |     317719 |      62695 |      50413
 5. |     149125 |     356471 |      61447 |      57487
 6. |     155355 |     322185 |      50254 |      35214
 7. |     140269 |     316224 |      61482 |      53889
 8. |     154454 |     334814 |      58382 |      53796
 9. |     177426 |     340723 |      62195 |      54352
10. |     151951 |     331772 |      61802 |      46727
Average Values:
    |   169387.5 |   329891.5 |    59428.2 |    51406.0
Ratio:
    |      1.000 |      1.948 |      0.351 |      0.303
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7fd844114f11712)

I wonder a little bit that the ratios on coliru (with only 4 threads) are even better than on my PC with (with 8 threads). Actually, I don't know how to explain this.
However, there are a lot of other differences in the two setups which may or may not be responsible. At least, both measurements show a rough speed-up of 3 for 3<sup>rd</sup> and 4<sup>th</sup> approach where the 2<sup>nd</sup> consumes uniquely every potential speed-up (probably by starting and joining all these threads).

Looking at the sample code, you will recognize that there is no mutex or any other explicit locking. This is intentionally. As I've learned (many, many years ago), every attempt for parallelization may cause a certain extra amount of communication overhead (for concurrent tasks which have to exchange data). If communication overhead becomes to big, it simply consumes the speed advantage of concurrency. So, best speed-up can be achieved by:

- least communication overhead i.e. concurrent tasks operate on independent data
- least effort for post-merging the concurrently computed results.

In my sample code, I

1. prepared every data and storage before starting the threads,
2. shared data which is read is never changed while threads are running,
3. data which is written as it were thread-local (no two threads write to the same address of data)
4. evaluate the computed results after all threads have been joined.

Concerning 3. I struggled a bit whether this is legal or not i.e. is it granted for data which is written in threads to appear correctly in main thread after joining. (The fact that something *seems* to work fine is illusive in general but especially illusive concerning multi-threading.)

cppreference.com provides the following explanations

- for [`std::thread::thread()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread)

  > The completion of the invocation of the constructor *synchronizes-with* (as defined in [`std::memory_order`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order)) the beginning of the invocation of the copy of *f* on the new thread of execution.
- for [`std::thread::join()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join)

  > The completion of the thread identified by `*this` *synchronizes with* the corresponding successful return from **join()**.

In Stack Overflow, I found the following related Q/A's:

- [Does relaxed memory order effect can be extended to after performing-thread's life?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32338113/7478597)
- [Are memory fences required here?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41427432/7478597)
- [Is there an implicit memory barrier with synchronized-with relationship on thread::join?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42177543/7478597)

which convinced me, it is OK.

However, the drawback is that

- the creation and joining of threads causes additional effort (and it's not that cheap).

An alternative approach could be the usage of a thread pool to overcome this. I googled a bit and found e.g. [Jakob Progsch's ThreadPool on github](https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool). However, I guess, with a thread pool the locking issue is back “in the game”.

Whether this will work for Eigen functions as well, depends on how the resp. Eigen functions are implemented. If there are accesses to global variables in them (which become shared when the same function is called concurrently), this will cause a data race.

Googling a bit, I found the following doc.

[Eigen and multi-threading – Using Eigen in a multi-threaded application](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html):

> In the case your own application is multithreaded, and multiple threads make calls to [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/namespaceEigen.html), then you have to initialize [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/namespaceEigen.html) by calling the following routine before creating the threads:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  Eigen::initParallel();
  ...
}
```

> **Note**
>
> With [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/namespaceEigen.html) 3.3, and a fully C++11 compliant compiler (i.e., [thread-safe static local variable initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables)), then calling `initParallel()` is optional.
>
> **Warning**
>
> note that all functions generating random matrices are **not** re-entrant nor thread-safe. Those include [DenseBase::Random()](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#ae814abb451b48ed872819192dc188c19), and [DenseBase::setRandom()](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#ac476e5852129ba32beaa1a8a3d7ee0db) despite a call to Eigen::initParallel(). This is because these functions are based on std::rand which is not re-entrant. For thread-safe random generator, we recommend the use of boost::random or c++11 random feature.