# How can I parallelize the process of copying the rows of a matrix randomly to another matrix in memory?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I have a matrix, call it `small_matrix` made up of about 100000 rows and 128 columns stored as a single array (I'm using it for CUDA calculations so the saved space is needed). I have a larger matrix, call it `large_matrix`, with 10x the number of rows and the same row length as `small_matrix` and I want to populate its rows with the rows from as `small_matrix`. However, the population process isn't 1:1. There is a `map` array that maps every row in `large_matrix` to a row in `small_matrix`. A single row in `small_matrix` can be mapped to by multiple rows in `large_matrix`. We can assume that the map array is randomly generated. Also, there is a small chance (assume it to be 1%) that a row in `large_matrix` will have random values instead of actual values.

I'm trying to optimize this process by means of parallelism using OMP on C++ but I just cannot seem to be able to. Anything I've tried so far has only lead to **increasing the runtime with more threads instead of decreasing it**. Here is the problem's code, I'm trying to optimize expand_matrix:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <random>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstddef>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

inline void* aligned_malloc(size_t size, size_t align){
    void *result;
    #ifdef _MSC_VER 
    result = _aligned_malloc(size, align);
    #else 
     if(posix_memalign(&result, align, size)) result = 0;
    #endif
    return result;
}
inline void aligned_free(void *ptr) {
    #ifdef _MSC_VER 
        _aligned_free(ptr);
    #else 
      free(ptr);
    #endif

}

void expand_matrix(int num_rows_in_large_matrix, int row_length, long long* map,  float*small_matrix, float* large_matrix, const int num_threads);


int main(){
    int row_length = 128;
    long long small_matrix_rows = 100000;
    long long large_matrix_rows = 1000000;
    long long *map = new long long [large_matrix_rows]; 
    float *small_matrix = (float*)aligned_malloc(small_matrix_rows*128*sizeof(float), 128);
    float *large_matrix = (float*)aligned_malloc(large_matrix_rows*128*sizeof(float), 128);

    minstd_rand gen(std::random_device{}()); //NOTE: Valgrind will give an error saying: vex amd64->IR: unhandled instruction bytes: 0xF 0xC7 0xF0 0x89 0x6 0xF 0x42 0xC1 :: look: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/valgrind/+bug/
    uniform_real_distribution<double> values_dist(0, 1);
    uniform_int_distribution<long long> map_dist(0,small_matrix_rows);
    for (long long i = 0; i<small_matrix_rows*row_length;i++){
        small_matrix[i] = values_dist(gen)-0.5;
    }
    for (long long i=0; i<large_matrix_rows;i++){
        if (values_dist(gen)<0.99)
            map[i] = map_dist(gen);
    }
    clock_t start, end;
    int num_threads =4;
    printf("Populated matrix and generated map\n");
    start = clock();
    expand_matrix(large_matrix_rows, row_length, map, small_matrix, large_matrix, num_threads);
    end = clock();
    printf("Time to expand using %d threads = %f\n", num_threads, double(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}



void expand_matrix(int num_rows_in_large_matrix, int row_length, long long* map,  float*small_matrix, float* large_matrix, const int num_threads){

  #pragma omp parallel num_threads(num_threads)
  {
    #pragma omp for schedule(guided, 4) 
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < num_rows_in_large_matrix; i++ ){
      long long sml = map[i];
      if(sml == -1){
        for (int j = 0; j < row_length; j++)
          large_matrix[i * row_length + j] = 0.5;
      }
      else{
        memcpy(large_matrix+i*row_length, small_matrix+sml*row_length, row_length*sizeof(float));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here are some runtimes:

```
Time to expand using 1 threads = 0.402949
Time to expand using 2 threads = 0.530361
Time to expand using 4 threads = 0.608085
Time to expand using 8 threads = 0.667806
Time to expand using 16 threads = 0.999886
```

I've made sure the matrices were aligned with memory, I've tried using non-temporal instructions for copying, I am stumped. I don't know where to look anymore. Any help is much appreciated.

Some hardware information:

```
CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v4 @ 2.10GHz
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              20480K
```

Using Ubuntu 16.04 and gcc version 5.5.0 20171010 (Ubuntu 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04).

Comment: It is data copying. How do you think it can be parallelized? You can parallelize computation and managing where the data goes but how much do you think your CPU is actually used in pure data copying? It is mostly limited to RAM's performance which is shared amongst CPUs.

Comment: Try using `omp_get_wtime()` instead of `clock()` and let us know.

Comment: See, that's what I thought as well but I figured that maybe somehow someway I can dispatch more copy instructions parallely which would push the bus to produce its bandwidth limit.

Comment: @Gilles I am out fo words. I switched out clock() for omp_get_wtime() and suddenly the parallelism works. Please please please tell me you have an explanation for this. Here are the runtimes after switching out clock() for omp_get_wtime:
`1 thread = 0.423516 - 4 threads = 0.152680
8 threads = 0.090841 - 16 threads = 0.064748`

Comment: `clock()` measures CPU time which increases with the number of CPU you add. `omp_get_wtime()` measures the wallclock time which is the one you want to see decreasing

Comment: FYI: [SO: Multi-threading benchmarking issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52835213/7478597).

Comment: @Gilles Thank you very much. I don't know how I missed this, honestly. I can't accept your comment as an answer but I'll write an answer and quote you if that's okay with you.

Comment: @Zulan Yes, it does thank you very much.

Comment: Sure go ahead, fine with me

Comment: @Scheff very interesting read! The cache utilization approach is very elegant and the results are impressive. I don't think I can adapt this approach to my problem, though. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Gilles and @Zulan for pointing out the error. I will post it as an answer so others can see the issue. I was using the wrong time measurement method; my method does not work with multithreaded applications. In other words, I misused the `clock()` function. Here is @Giller's answer:

> `clock()` measures CPU time which increases with the number of CPU you add. `omp_get_wtime()` measures the wallclock time which is the one you want to see decreasing

the function I'm using to measure the time of the function execution is `clock()`. This function counts the number of processor ticks taken by all the processors involved in running the code. When I run my code in parallel using multiple processors, the clock ticks returned by `clock()` are the total of all the processors and so the number is only increasing as I increase the number of processors. When I switched the time measurement to `omp_get_wtime()` the timing returned was correct and I got the following results:

```
1 thread = 0.423516
4 threads = 0.152680 
8 threads = 0.090841
16 threads = 0.064748
```

So, instead of measuring the runtime like this:

```
    clock_t start, end;
    start = clock();
    expand_matrix(large_matrix_rows, row_length, map, small_matrix, large_matrix, num_threads);
    end = clock();
    printf("Total time %f\n", double(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

I do it like this:

```
    double start, end;
    start = omp_get_wtime();
    expand_matrix(large_matrix_rows, row_length, map, small_matrix, large_matrix, num_threads);
    end = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("Total time %f\n", end-start);
```