# Accessing shared vector in multi-threaded application

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've got a bunch of threads working on getting a result and storing it in a shared vector.

Right now I am doing this in the following way, but am wondering if there is a *faster* way of doing it (speed is the only priority here so please focus on that), e.g. to avoid false sharing and the like.

Globally, there exists a vector

```
std::vector<double> allResults;
```

and each thread stores its results in this vector by writing

```
std::for_each(allResults.begin() + i, allResults.begin() + i + n, 
    [](double& res) 
    { 
    res = .... //Calculate result and store it.
    });
```

Here, for each thread, `i, n` are indeces  that correspond to a range of results that the current thread is supposed to calculate: `allResults[i], ...., allResults[i + n - 1]`. These ranges are **unique** for every thread. So each thread is working on its own range of results, without overlaps.

Comment: Are the threads joined before `allResults` is evaluated?

Comment: Yes, the main thread waits for all threads to complete first.

Comment: To avoid false sharing you need `sizeof(double) * n` to be evenly divisible by the cache line size.  That can be tricky to do in portable code though.

Comment: I recently did something similar in [SO: Eigen library with C++11 multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52724681/7478597) (My answer didn't rely on Eigen.) and [SO: Multi-threading benchmarking issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52835213/7478597). When I wrote the first, I was in doubt for quite the same reasons and googled a bit. So, the first answer contains some notes and links about this.

Comment: Why not let each thread work with individual vectors and then merge them at the end? I would start with that implementation and improve only after profiling.

Comment: You need to `reserve()` the space first and make sure to never resize the `vector` while working on it's elements in different threads. Also make sure that writes from different threads are separated by >64 bytes or else performance will suffer from false sharing.

Comment: In addition to @NathanOliver: Concerning the issue of false cache sharing, I recently got a link from a colaborator (which I've not yet fully read and understood): [Eliminate False Sharing](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/eliminate-false-sharing/217500206).

Comment: Try this: Split the vector by the amount of threads. Each split is a separate vector. Have the threads work only on their vector. When all done, merge the vectors in to 1.

Comment: The advice of splitting the vectors and having each thread work with its own vector definitely seems to work, I got the code running faster... but the trouble is I actually don't know how much work a vector will do beforehand. So now I have the choice between allocating a very large vector for each thread (I know the MAX amount of work so I could create vectors of that size) or giving it a smaller size and then resizing as needed. Probably going to have to run some tests to see what works best.